# Isn't this prior art

Tags: prior-art-request, us20070040653

In the patent application US20070040653, it appears that patent US20060187055 "Containers including radio frequency shielding" might be prior art. Is this the case?

EDIT

> 1. A method of preventing unauthorized electromagnetic access to an RFID device embedded within a card comprising the steps of:
>
>    providing at least one length of electromagnetic shielding material; and
>
>    substantially surrounding the card having the RFID device embedded therein with the length of electromagnetic shielding material.
> 2. An apparatus for preventing unauthorized electronic access to an RFID device embedded within a card comprising:
>
>    at least one length of electromagnetic shielding material; and
>
>    means for positioning the length of electromagnetic shielding material in a surrounding relationship with respect to the card having the RFID device embedded therein.

Answer (score 1):

This patent application was declared abandoned in 2010. That information is visible at a USPTO site called Public PAIR. It allows the public to see *all* of the paperwork back-and-forth between the applicant and the examiner. I am inserting a screen shot of the status of this application.
[image]